# I have Project in Netbeans name(DemoApp) where log files are stored of this project?

Tags: java, logging, netbeans

In my Netbeans i have project DemoApp and i'm using tomcat,in my project i have 2 packages named pkg1,pkg2 in that i have servlet1,servlet2 programs in pkg1 and servlet3,servlet4 in pkg2.And i'm using  Logger like this

```
 try {
           //some code
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(servlet1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

then where my log files are stored related to my project and its classes.
Your answer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where your source files are,you can right click on your project in netbeans and select properties.It will open a dialog and will show you the directory structure where all the source files get stored.

If you want to know where your log is getting generated,you need to check your logger properties file.
You can configure these properties to write output to a file or database as per your requirement.

Comment: I want to know my log files storing of my particular project

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `Logger` class simply prints to the console. You need to manually register a new `Handler` object with it to get it to direct it's output elsewhere; for example, if you have a Logger l, you can use`l.addHandler(new FileHandler("myfile.log"));`. This tells `l` to append it's output to a file called myfile.log; since paths in Java are relative to the current working directory, and you are using NetBeans, you should find myfile.log located next to your DemoApp.java file.

Comment: Nekojimi,that means by default log files wont store any where if dont use Handler object?

Comment: @abdul, yes, normally no log files are stored at all.